# Everytime I reboot my laptop I have to setup Django in Pycharm again. Error Please enable Django Support for the project

Tags: django, pycharm

I'm using pycharm and everytime I restart my laptop I have to always configure the Django root folder and the settings in pycharm.

I always get this error before trying to run my django server:
[image]

This are the fields I always have to configure:

[image]

Comment: Did you try contacting Pycharm tech support team? Assuming you have enterprise edition.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `.idea` in working directory with `rm -rf .idea`

Comment: will it be created again after removing it?

Comment: @user2880391 yes, it will be created on the next PyCharm start.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in running both WebStorm and PyCharm in the same directory. Something in `.idea/` got overwritten by the other IDE.
Solved by using PyCharm for Django subdir only.